# Spectrum Cauchy-Euler operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

A Cauchy-Euler operator is an operator that leaves homogeneous polynomial of a certain degree invariant, named after the [Cauchy-Euler differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)

We consider the operator
$$(Lf)(x) = \langle Ax,\nabla \rangle \langle \nabla,Ax \rangle f(x),$$
where $A \in \mathbf C^{d \times d}$ is a constant matrix and $\nabla$ the gradient.

I am asking what the spectrum of $L$ on the space of all homogeneous polynomial is?

Let me illustrate this for the case $d=1:$

Then $$Lf(x) = \vert a \vert^2 x \partial_x^2( x f(x)) =\vert a \vert^2 (x^2 f''(x)+2x f'(x)). $$
If we then assume that $f(x)=x^m$ with $m \ge 0$ we see that
$$Lf(x) = \vert a \vert^2 (m(m-1)+2m) f(x) = \vert a \vert^2 m(m+1) f(x).$$

Thus, the spectrum is precisely $\vert a \vert^2 m(m+1)$ where $m \in \mathbb N_0$ is arbitrary.

Comment: See the complete solution below.

Comment: @DenisSerre it is quite remarkable, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miscellaneous results.

- If $A$ is strictly upper triangular, then $x\cdot\nabla$ consists only is terms $x_j\partial_k$ with $j<k$. The action of $L$ over homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ is described, in the basis of monomials written in lexicographic order, by a strictly upper triangular matrix. hence the only eigenvalue is $\lambda=0$.

In general
\begin{eqnarray*}
Lf & = & (Ax\cdot\nabla){\rm div}(fAx)=(Ax\cdot\nabla)(\nabla f\cdot Ax+f{\rm Tr}A) \\
& = & (Ax)^T\nabla^2f(Ax)+\nabla f\cdot(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})x.
\end{eqnarray*}

- Degree one (linear forms). One has
  $$L[v\cdot x]=v\cdot(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})x.$$
  The eigenforms correspond to eigenvectors of $(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})^T$. The eigenvalues are the numbers $a(a+{\rm Tr}A)$ where $a\in\sigma(A)$.
- Degree two (quadratic forms). One has
  $$L[\frac12x^TSx]=(Ax)^TS(Ax)+(Sx)\cdot(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})x.$$
  The eigenpairs correspond to the symmetric matrices $S$ solutions of
  $$2A^TSA+S(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})+(A^2+A{\rm Tr A})^TS=\lambda S,$$
  where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

If $a\in\sigma(A)$ and $A^Tv=av$, then $S=vv^T$ is a solution, with
$$\lambda=4a^2+2a{\rm Tr}A.$$
More generally, if $a,b\in\sigma(A)$, $A^Tv=av$ and $A^Tw=bw$, then $S=vw^T+wv^T$ is a solution, with
$$\lambda=(a+b)^2+(a+b){\rm Tr}A.$$

**Edit**. The examples above path the way to a general solution. Consider the action of $L$ over forms (homogeneous polynomials) of degree $d$. Then we obtain eigenforms as follows. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_d$ be a list of numbers, all of them being eigenvalues of $A$ (repetition is allowed). Let $v_j$ be an eigenvector of $A^T$ associated with $a_j$, that is $A^Tv_j=a_jv_j$. Then
$$f(x):=\prod_jv_j\cdot x$$
satisfies
$$Lf=\lambda f,\qquad\lambda=\left(\sum_ja_j\right)^2+\left(\sum_ja_j\right){\rm Tr} A.$$
To see this, remark that
$$\nabla f=f\sum_j\frac{v_j}{v_j\cdot x},\qquad\nabla^2 f=f\sum_{j\ne k}\frac{v_j}{v_j\cdot x}\otimes\frac{v_k}{v_k\cdot x}.$$

If $A$ has simple eigenvalues, ordered in some way $\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n$, then you obtain an eigenform for every $n$-uplet $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ such that $m_1+\cdots+m_n=d$, where you take $m_1$ times $\mu_1$ in the list $(a_j)_j$, etc... The number of $n$-uplets, summing up to $d$, being equal to the dimension of forms of degree $d$ in $n$ variables, this gives a diagonalisation of $L$. Actually, one can see the products as monomials in the system of coordinates $(v_1\cdot x,\ldots,v_n\cdot x)$.

By a continuity argument, the spectrum of $L$ over $d$-forms is always the set of numbers
$$\left(\sum_ja_j\right)^2+\left(\sum_ja_j\right){\rm Tr} A,$$
counted with multiplicities.

Comment: @Sascha Of course, this is only the beginning of a hierarchy. But it seems more and more complicated as the degree increases. Let me think about that.